# How to set the index of a combobox that was dynamically added to a datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

So here is a bit of backstory to try and put things into context

First off the format of the data:
I have two databases that are structured like this

`DB1` this table contains the `Field_Id`, along with all of the properties of the field
`DB2` this table contains broader information along with references to DB1 `Field_Id`, that reference is used for getting the `Field_Name`

so simple sql query to better describe

```
Select Field_Name From DB1 Where Field_Id = (select Field_Id From DB2 where param = %)
```

this returns a list that gets bound to a `DataGridViewComboBox` inside of a datatable. Now up to this point everything goes great, the `ComboBox` get added the whole `DataGridView` gets filled the issue arises here

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 2; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = valuetosetindex;
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }
```

The thing is this doesnt set the value of the `ComboBox` inside of the 0th column, if I were to just set the columns to strings it works but the value set doesnt work.

Im more than happy to add more code if needed.

Comment: Show how you're setting the DataSource of the DGV and the DGV's ComboBox column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code snippet you are going to add an invalid value to the object which results in an `ArgumentException`.

Like you have already mentioned, if you assign a string to the value it is working. You only have to access the `valuetosetindex` element of the `ComboBox`:

`dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = yourColumn.Items[valuetosetindex];`

In this code snippet `yourColumn` is your `ComboBox` which is bound to the column.

Comment: Hello Mario, so the issue with that is the combobox is being added dynamically by creating a list and then inserting it into a datatable and binding that datatable to the datagridview. Your solution would work if not the case.

Comment: @DigitPlays, then you have to use your list instead of `yourColumn.Items[valuetosetindex]`. For example: `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = yourList[valuetosetindex];`

Answer (score 0):

How is your Datagridview bound to data? I would suggest to use a Dataset and a BindingSource to tie it togehter.
If you bind it you can choose to use a ComboBox as a column type. Then you can bind a second dataset to that Combobox. this would automatically create the link.